# How can I separate each slides from one PPT file that has 100 slides?

Tags: powerpoint

I have a powerpoint file(Power point 2016) which has 100 page(slides). What I want is to automatically separate each slide to create 100 separate powerpoint files with keeping the existing masterslide features, design and layout. Is there any way to do that easily ?

Answer (score 0):

Hello I found the answer and this is giving what I want to reach. For your informations.

```
Sub splitFiles()
    Dim tempR As Presentation
    Dim opres As Presentation
    Dim L As Long
    Dim oFolder As String
    'requires v. 2010 or later
    On Error Resume Next
    Set opres = ActivePresentation
    Set tempR = Presentations.Add
    tempR.PageSetup.SlideSize = opres.PageSetup.SlideSize
    oFolder = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\Files\"
    MkDir oFolder
    For L = 1 To opres.Slides.Count
        opres.Slides(L).Copy
        tempR.Windows(1).Panes(1).Activate
        Call CommandBars.ExecuteMso("PasteSourceFormatting")
        Call tempR.SaveCopyAs(oFolder & "Slide" & CStr(L) & ".pptx", ppSaveAsOpenXMLPresentation)
        tempR.Slides(1).Delete
    Next L
    tempR.Saved = True
    tempR.Close
End Sub
```